# Outlook 2010 address access problem

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 addresses missing problem -

I've tried everything to find the addresses to send my e-mails and although there's a ton of addresses in my contacts file there's no addresses or access to addresses when I try to send e-mails to anyone - zero, none, nada!!

All the contacts are there in Outlook 2010 with full addresses and contact info but they won't transfer into my e-mail address book which remains firmly empty.  There's pst files and you name it but how do I get them into the address listings for the emails?

Thanks for any help you can give me.
N Spokes. PhD FWiW

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the auto-complete, you can use `CTRL+K` to do a name lookup for a partially typed name.

If there are contacts in your address book with email addresses listed this should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Find your contacts folder (Ctrl-3 shows Contacts in navigation pane)

right click > properties

Outlook address book tab

Make sure box is ticked to "show this folder as an e-mail address book". (this is on by default in 2010).

If this does not work it is possible your pst file is corrupt, scanpst.exe may help.